# Efeito touch/clica e arrasta com mouse

Tags: javascript, html, css, javascript-eventos

Tenho uma galeria com scroll horizontal, gostaria de saber se é possível colocar um clica e arrasta para mover o scroll, como se fosse um touch arrastando com o mouse.

obs: as imagens possuirão link.

minha galeria:

```js
function mostra(theId){
 var theArray= new Array('item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6');
 for(i=0; i<theArray.length; i++){
  if(theArray[i] == theId){
   document.getElementById(theId).style.display='block';
  }else{
   document.getElementById(theArray[i]).style.display='none';
  }
 }
}

function exibe(theId){
 var theArray= new Array('item-1', 'item-2', 'item-3', 'item-4', 'item-5', 'item-6');
 for(i=0; i<theArray.length; i++){
  if(theArray[i] == theId){
   document.getElementById(theId).style.display='block';
  }else{
   document.getElementById(theArray[i]).style.display='none';
  }
 }
}

var SETTINGS = {
    navBarTravelling: false,
    navBarTravelDirection: "",
  navBarTravelDistance: 150
}

var colours = {
    0: "#00BFFF",
    1: "#32CD32",
    2: "#FF0000",
    3: "#40FEFF",
    4: "#14CC99",
    5: "#00BAFF",
    6: "#0082B2",
    7: "#B25D7A",
    8: "#00FF17",
    9: "#006B49",
    10: "#00B27A",
    11: "#996B3D",
    12: "#CC7014",
    13: "#40FF8C",
    14: "#FF3400",
    15: "#ECBB5E",
    16: "#ECBB0C",
    17: "#B9D912",
    18: "#253A93",
    19: "#125FB9",
}


document.documentElement.classList.remove("no-js");
document.documentElement.classList.add("js");

// the indicator
var indicador = document.getElementById("indicador");
var trilho = document.getElementById("trilho");

// Set the indicator
moveIndicator(trilho.querySelector("[aria-selected=\"true\"]"), colours[0]);


// Handle setting the currently active link
trilhoContents.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
 var links = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".trilho_classe_Link"));
 links.forEach(function(item) {
  item.setAttribute("aria-selected", "false");
 })
 e.target.setAttribute("aria-selected", "true");
 // Pass the clicked item and it's colour to the move indicator function
 moveIndicator(e.target, colours[links.indexOf(e.target)]);
});


// var count = 0;
function moveIndicator(item, color) {
    var textPosition = item.getBoundingClientRect();
    var container = trilhoContents.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    var distance = textPosition.left - container;
  var scroll = trilhoContents.scrollLeft;
    indicador.style.transform = "translateX(" + (distance + scroll) + "px) scaleX(" + textPosition.width * 0.01 + ")";
 // count = count += 100;
 // indicador.style.transform = "translateX(" + count + "px)";
 
    if (color) {
        indicador.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}

function determineOverflow(content, container) {
    var containerMetrics = container.getBoundingClientRect();
    var containerMetricsRight = Math.floor(containerMetrics.right);
    var containerMetricsLeft = Math.floor(containerMetrics.left);
    var contentMetrics = content.getBoundingClientRect();
    var contentMetricsRight = Math.floor(contentMetrics.right);
    var contentMetricsLeft = Math.floor(contentMetrics.left);
  if (containerMetricsLeft > contentMetricsLeft && containerMetricsRight < contentMetricsRight) {
        return "both";
    } else if (contentMetricsLeft < containerMetricsLeft) {
        return "left";
    } else if (contentMetricsRight > containerMetricsRight) {
        return "right";
    } else {
        return "none";
    }
}

var indicador2 = document.getElementById("indicador2");
var trilho2 = document.getElementById("trilho2");

var colours2 = {
    0: "#00BFFF",
    1: "#32CD32",
    2: "#FF0000",
    3: "#40FEFF",
    4: "#14CC99",
    5: "#00BAFF",
    6: "#0082B2",
    7: "#B25D7A",
    8: "#00FF17",
    9: "#006B49",
    10: "#00B27A",
    11: "#996B3D",
    12: "#CC7014",
    13: "#40FF8C",
    14: "#FF3400",
    15: "#ECBB5E",
    16: "#ECBB0C",
    17: "#B9D912",
    18: "#253A93",
    19: "#125FB9",
}

// var count = 0;
function moveIndicator2(item, color) {
    var textPosition = item.getBoundingClientRect();
    var container = trilhoContents2.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    var distance = textPosition.left - container;
  var scroll = trilhoContents2.scrollLeft;
    indicador2.style.transform = "translateX(" + (distance + scroll) + "px) scaleX(" + textPosition.width * 0.01 + ")";
 // count = count += 100;
 // indicador.style.transform = "translateX(" + count + "px)";
 
    if (color) {
        indicador2.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}

// Set the indicator
moveIndicator2(trilho2.querySelector("[aria-selected=\"true\"]"), colours2[0]);


// Handle setting the currently active link
trilhoContents2.addEventListener("click", function(f) {
 var links = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".trilho_classe_Link2"));
 links.forEach(function(item) {
  item.setAttribute("aria-selected", "false");
 })
 f.target.setAttribute("aria-selected", "true");
 // Pass the clicked item and it's colour to the move indicator function
 moveIndicator2(f.target, colours2[links.indexOf(f.target)]);
});
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: inherit;
}

.menu_horizontal {
 position: relative;
 /*padding: 0 11px;*/
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.trilho_classe {
    /* Make this scrollable when needed */
    overflow-x: auto;
    /* We don't want vertical scrolling */
    overflow-y: hidden;
    /* For WebKit implementations, provide inertia scrolling */
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    /* We don't want internal inline elements to wrap */
    white-space: nowrap;
    /* If JS present, let's hide the default scrollbar */
    .js & {
        /* Make an auto-hiding scroller for the 3 people using a IE */
        -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
        /* Remove the default scrollbar for WebKit implementations */
        &::-webkit-scrollbar {
            display: none;
        }
    }
 /* positioning context for advancers */
 position: relative;
 /*Crush the whitespace here*/
 font-size: 0;
}

.trilho_classe_Contents {
 float: left;
 transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
 position: relative;
}

.trilho_classe_Contents-no-transition {
 transition: none;
}

.trilho_classe_Link {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #888;
 /*Reset the font size*/
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 font-family: -apple-system, sans-serif;
 display: inline-flex;
 align-items: center;
 min-height: 44px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 padding: 0 11px;
 & + & {
  border-left-color: #eee;
 }
 &[aria-selected="true"] {
  color: #111;
 }
}

.trilho_classe_Indicator {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 4px;
 width: 100px;
 background-color: transparent;
 transform-origin: 0 0;
 transition: transform .2s ease-in-out, background-color .2s ease-in-out;
}
 
.trilho_classe_Link2 {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #888;
 /*Reset the font size*/
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 font-family: -apple-system, sans-serif;
 display: inline-flex;
 align-items: center;
 min-height: 44px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 padding: 0 11px;
 & + & {
  border-left-color: #eee;
 }
 &[aria-selected="true"] {
  color: #111;
 }
}

#caixas{
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  
 }
 #caixas2{
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  
 }
  .conteudocaixas{
   overflow-x: scroll;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .imagemcaixas{
   margin-top: 5px;
   width: 12.15%;
   max-width: 170px;
   height: auto;
   display: inline-block;
  }
  .position_btcx{
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 6px 10px 0 0;
      float: right;
  }
  .button_cx{
   background: #fff;
   height: 30px;
   width: 30px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   border-radius: 5px;
   margin-right: 5px;
  }
  
 .caixa1{
  /*margin: 0 0.5% 0 0.5%;*/
 }
 .caixa2{
  /*margin: 0 0.5% 0 0.5%;*/
 }
 .logocx{
  width: 130px;
  height: 44px;
  float:  left;
  display: -webkit-box;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 15px;
 }
 .logocx img{
  width: 15px;
 }
 .logocx p{
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 0;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="caixas">
 <div class="caixa1">
  <div class="menu_horizontal">
   <nav id="trilho" class="trilho_classe">
    
    <div id="trilhoContents" class="trilho_classe_Contents">
     <a onclick="mostra('item1');" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link" aria-selected="true">Galeria1</a>
     <a onclick="mostra('item2');" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link" aria-selected="false">Galeria2</a>
     <a onclick="mostra('item3');" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link" aria-selected="false">Galeria3</a>
    <span id="indicador" class="trilho_classe_Indicator" style="transform: translateX(0px) scaleX(0.965781); background-color: rgb(0, 191, 255);"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="position_btcx">
     <button class="button_cx" type="button">&lt;</button>
     <button class="button_cx" type="button">&gt;</button>
    </div>
   </nav>
   <div id="item1" style="display: block;">
    <div class="conteudocaixas">
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div id="item2" style="display: none;">
    <div class="conteudocaixas">
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div id="item3" style="display: none;">
    <div class="conteudocaixas">
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>



 <div class="caixa1">
  <div class="menu_horizontal">
   <nav id="trilho2" class="trilho_classe">
    
    <div id="trilhoContents2" class="trilho_classe_Contents">
     <a onclick="exibe('item-1');" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link2" aria-selected="true">Galeria1</a>
     <a onclick="exibe('item-2');" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link2">Galeria2</a>
     <a onclick="exibe('item-3');" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link2">Galeria3</a>
    <span id="indicador2" class="trilho_classe_Indicator"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="position_btcx">
     <button class="button_cx" type="button">&lt;</button>
     <button class="button_cx" type="button">&gt;</button>
    </div>
   </nav>
   <div id="item-1" style="display:block;">
    <div class="conteudocaixas">
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div id="item-2" style="display:none;">
    <div class="conteudocaixas">
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div id="item-3" style="display:none;">
    <div class="conteudocaixas">
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe uma biblioteca bem simples que pode lhe ajudar nisso, que é a [dragscroll](https://github.com/asvd/dragscroll). Basta importar no seu arquivo HTML.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dragscroll/0.0.8/dragscroll.min.js"></script>
```

E adicionar a classe **dragscroll** nas divs com a classe **conteudocaixas**

```
<div class="conteudocaixas dragscroll">
  <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Sensacional, quebrei a cabeça de mais com isso!
Muito Obrigado!

Comment: agora meu problema é os links que abrem quando arrasto a div